# Opencv error Assertion failed while using CopyTo function

Tags: opencv

I have a vector of images and vector of descriptor values extracted using HOG descriptor in Opencv:

```
vector<Mat> images;
vector< vector < float> > v_descriptorsValues;
```

These vectors are previously initialized with proper images and values. The part of the code that causes an Opencv error :

```
    Mat reData(images.size(), v_descriptorsValues[0].size(),true);

    for (int i=0; i< images.size(); i++)
          Mat(v_descriptorsValues[i]).copyTo(reData.row(i));
```

And the Opencv error i got:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == _sz) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1344
```

Actually in the last line of code i want to copy all the element of `v_descriptorsValues` to `reData` Mat.
Any idea that can solve the problem?

Comment: By doing `Mat reData(images.size(), v_descriptorsValues[0].size(),true);`, you're calling [constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) `Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)`, which maybe not what you want.

Comment: @herohuyongtao- you mean i should not call the constructor? Even if i just use `Mat reData;` for definition again this error comes out!